# php regex find a string that's NOT of a certain length

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to use preg_match_all to check for syntax errors with comma, where "hello, there" is ok but not "hello,there".

First I realize that a space, double quote, and line break are all acceptable after a comma, so I believe I can do 
`preg_match_all("/(,[^ \r\n\"])/", $mystring, $result);`
and anything returning means there's a syntax error.

Then I realize commas also appear in numbers, eg. 1,234,567, so I need to allow 3-digit numbers in my regex. If I'm purely searching for a 3-digit number, I know I can do
    `preg_match_all("/(\d{3})/", $mystring, $result);`

But in this case I want to *exclude* 3-digit numbers, ie. the regex should say "match all that have a comma followed by something NOT space, NOT line break, and *NOT a 3-digit number*". The "and NOT a 3-digit number" part threw me off; I thought I could just do 
    `preg_match_all("/(,[^ \r\n\"\d{3}])/", $mystring, $result);` but that doesn't seem to be it. What did I do wrong here? And is there a simpler way to accomplish this search?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something more simple like searching for a comma followed by *illegal* number of spaces?

Like `,\s{2,}`

Obviously this gets more complex if you're throwing in NOT validations. For those, you'll need [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

`,\s(?!\d)` == [comma][whitespace][notfollowedbynumber]
`(?<!\d),\s` == [notprecededbynumber][comma][whitespace]

Answer (score 0):

negative lookahead using `,(?![ \r\n\"]|\d{3})`